# psql and trigger behaviour

Tags: postgresql, psql, dump

I'm restoring a sql dump with a psql command:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -U master -d dbname -f sqldump.sql
```

My database has several event triggers and just ordinary triggers on the tables.

Does **psql** turn them off during restoration(as far as I saw event triggers were turned off by **psql**)? I would like to know the exact commands psql does in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psql` will not disable event triggers. What makes you think so?

Event triggers by default are only triggered if the parameter [`session_replication_role`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SESSION-REPLICATION-ROLE) is set to is set to `local` or `origin`, so you can prevent event triggers from firing by setting the parameter to `replica` (that won't work for event triggers that have `ENABLE REPLICA` or `ENABLE ALWAYS`).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was because `create event trigger` events are located in the end of the sql dump. Nevermind